# Linq left outer join not working using DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

Using the technique found on the MSDN article ["How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx), I attempted to create a left outer join in my Linq code. The article mentions using the `DefaultIfEmpty` method in order to create a left outer join from a group join. Basically, it instructs the program to include the results of the left (first) collection even if there are no results in the right collection.

The way this program executes, however, it does so as if the outer join has not been specified.

In our database, `AgentProductTraining` is a collection of courses our agents have taken. Normally you cannot enter a `Course` onto it's appropriate table without entering a corresponding value into the `CourseMaterials` table. However, occasionally this may happen, so we want to make sure we return results even when a `Course` is listed in `AgentProductTraining` without any corresponding information in `CourseMaterials`.

```
var training = from a in db.AgentProductTraining
    join m in db.CourseMaterials on a.CourseCode equals m.CourseCode into apm
    where
        a.SymNumber == id 
        from m in apm.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where m.EffectiveDate <= a.DateTaken
        && ((m.TerminationDate > a.DateTaken) | (m.TerminationDate == null))
            select new
            {
                a.AgentProdTrainId,
                a.CourseCode,
                a.Course.CourseDescription,
                a.Course.Partner,
                a.DateTaken,
                a.DateExpired,
                a.LastChangeOperator,
                a.LastChangeDate,
                a.ProductCode,
                a.Product.ProductDescription,
                m.MaterialId,
                m.Description,
                a.Method
            };
```

Comment: Is there a navigation property `AgentProductTraining.CourseMaterials`?

Comment: Also, the title says _left inner join not working_, but I assume it's the outer join? In fact, there's not really a problem statement in your post.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks. I do not believe we have a navigation property on `CourseMaterials`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN example uses a new variable `subpet`:

```
var query = from person in people
                    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```

So you must use your own "subpet", I rewrote your code using the `submat` variable:

```
        var training = from a in db.AgentProductTraining
                       join m in db.CourseMaterials on a.CourseCode equals m.CourseCode into apm
                       where
                           a.SymNumber == id
                           from submat in apm.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where 
                           (submat.EffectiveDate <= a.DateTaken || submat.EffectiveDate == null) &&
                           (submat.TerminationDate > a.DateTaken || submat.TerminationDate == null)
                       select new
                                  {
                                      a.AgentProdTrainId,
                                      a.CourseCode,
                                      a.Course.CourseDescription,
                                      a.Course.Partner,
                                      a.DateTaken,
                                      a.DateExpired,
                                      a.LastChangeOperator,
                                      a.LastChangeDate,
                                      a.ProductCode,
                                      a.Product.ProductDescription,
                                      MaterialId = (submat==null?-1:submat.MaterialId),
                                      Description = (submat==null?String.Empty:submat.Description),
                                      a.Method
                                  };
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting the following error message in the `Results View` section of the `training` variable (no clue why, currently looking into it) `The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`

Comment: I presume `submat.MaterialId` can not be null, so you'll have to set a default value in the case the outer joined is returning null (when there is no CourseMaterials for the AgentProductTraining record). I'll edit the code in order to set -1 in that case.

Comment: Sorry... VS2010 didn't like that. I get the message `Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declaure with a member assignment, simple name or member access`

Comment: Oh, means you must specify a name for those 2 members, let me edit the answer.

Comment: @NealR It's been a pleasure!